# Transform service types when using Bluemix Cloud Integration Service

Tags: integration, ibm-cloud

I have been doing some research about the IBM Bluemix Cloud Integration Service and found the following links:

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/cloud/bluemix/cloudintegration/Cloud_Integration_for_Bluemix_User_Guide.pdf

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudIntegration/index.html

From what I have read, I have not been able to understand whether it is able to run some kind of "protocol transformation" or if it just publishes a REST or SOAP API.

I mean, imagine for example that I have a full backend publishing everything as SOAP services, but for some reason my apps only can get information through REST APIs. Does the basic connector o maybe the standard one make that kind of integration? Or do I need to put a third party product (or maybe even DataPower) to make that transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Cloud Integration service you can also create a REST API that links to an existing on-premises API (both SOAP and REST). Please take a look here: [Creating a REST API that links to an existing on-premises API](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudIntegration/index-gentopic2.html#CldInt_REST_OnPrem). You can upload a file that defines the on-premises API (WSDL or Swagger definition).

Please note that currently Cloud Integration cannot retrieve automatically that definition from your on-premises system. It has to be uploaded manually by the user.

Comment: Hi Umberto, thank you for the response. So, this transformation would be within Bluemix or within the server running the basic connector?

Comment: It will be made on Bluemix. Your API is created and is available for use, SDK generation, access credentials, and so on.